# Using assumptions, weird output

Tags: assumptions, piecewise

I have a Piecewise function, of the type:

```
$Assumptions = b > a > 0
fun[k_] := Piecewise[{{3k, 0<=k<a}, {k^2, a<=k<=b}}]
fun[a]
```

When evaluating fun[a], the output I expect is a^2.
However Mathematica returns me the following output:

```
3a    0<=a<a
a^2   a<=a<=b
0     True
```

Why, how can I obtain a^2 and, most importantly, how can I tell Mathematica to consider b greater than a greater than 0 as assumption.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assumptions are not applied automatically.  A minimal way to apply them is to use `Refine`.  Other alternatives, such as `Simplify` could also be used, but will try more complicated transformations of your expression.

```
Refine[fun[a]]
(* a^2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.